# Dynamic programing in django not working properly

Tags: django, ajax

In django, tried to create a dynamic web page with ajax. But it doesn't takes the automatic reload. The requesting to the server is only done when reloading the page. Here my codes.
How i make into dynamic reloading.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from random import randrange

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
def random_generator(request):
    return HttpResponse(randrange(0, 100))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^main/$', 'Signup.views.main'),
    url('^random/$', 'Signup.views.random_generator')
)
```

**random.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshRandom() {
$.ajax({
        url: '/random/',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#random').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            window.setTimeout(refreshRandom, 1000);
        }
        });
}
window.setTimeout(refreshRandom, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='random'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // JQuery code to be added in here.

});
```

in your template use

```
<script src="{% static "/js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "/js/rango-ajax.js" %}"></script>
```